# How to take away (move out of) a struct field that contains a big datastructure type?

Tags: rust

I have a very large structure:

```
struct VeryLargeStructure {
    // many tens of fields here
}
```

And another structure that contains it in a field:

```
struct A {
  v: VeryLargeStructure 
}
```

How do I move value from the `v` field...

```
let a = A{/* ... */}
let b = a.v;
```

...*without having to construct a new instance of VeryLargeStructure* for `a.v`, because that will be non-performant and useless?

I am aware of `mem::replace` and `mem::swap`, but they do not satisfy said requirement.

I prefer safe approach, but I suspect there isn't one, so I am also ready for an `unsafe` one.

Comment: Would you be allowed to destroy your `A`? IE drop it?

Comment: @OptimisticPeach You mean the `A`'s instance `a`? Yes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incidentally, what you already have written works. This transfers ownership of `a.v` to `b` invalidates `a` (the old variable no longer exists). That means that we don't need to replace the data we took out with valid data. That's one of the benefits of having ownership versus mere mutable access.

```
let a = A {
    v: VeryLargeStructure {/* ... */},
};
let b = a.v;
// Now `b` has ownership of what was once `a.v`.
// `a` no longer exists as a single entity,
// but you could extract other fields too if you wish.
// E.g. `let c = a.w` if `w` is some other field of `a`.
```

In context,

```
struct VeryLargeStructure {
    // many tens of fields here
}

struct A {
    v: VeryLargeStructure,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        v: VeryLargeStructure {/* ... */},
    };
    let b = a.v;
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f326e98245da2c6845c07312d45d087)

---

The somewhat desugared version of this is [destructuring](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_structures.html). It can be used to easily extract several fields at once. For a single field, though, `let b = a.v;` is probably preferred since it's simpler and clearer.

```
struct VeryLargeStructure {
    // many tens of fields here
}

struct A {
    v: VeryLargeStructure,
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        v: VeryLargeStructure {/* ... */},
    };
    let A { v: b } = a;
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b58ebbbca839acc89d6b2374526872b2)

---

Note that if `A` implements `Drop`, it has to keep ownership of all its fields. That means you can never move out of it without replacement. Replacing data (e.g. with `mem::replace`) is fine, though.

Comment: Wow, great! I am surprised the code I've wrote for the question's example, does work. That's of course not the real code I have in my app. Everything is a bit complicated in there. While writing this, I am starting to realise, while your answer is really great, I will not be able to use it because of the same reasons, why Rust didn't let me to use a simple `let b = a.v;` (`a` is a property of a borrowed reference), but at least you gave me these precious ideas!

Comment: Regarding your note on `Drop`. I thought every struct implements `Drop` by default, isn't that the truth?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Nope. Yes, everything gets dropped (barring some special cases), but by default, structs drop recursively. This drops the fields independently, so they don't all have to be intact. Implementing `Drop` can override that, though. Since the `drop` method has (mutable) access to the object right before it's dropped, all the fields need to be intact. Try using the code in the answer with `impl Drop for A {fn drop(&mut self) {}}` added in to see the error.